# What did I miss? Issue with bubble sort method

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

I want to use a bubble sort method for my homework and it doesn't work, I can't find the mistake

```
 void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
   { 
     int i,j; 
     for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)       
      // last i elements are already in place    
     for (j = 0; j < n-i; j++) 
       if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
         swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
  }
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mcve]. Ans lastly please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the second loop stop condition should be n - i - 1

```
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
    int i, j; 
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)    
        // Last i elements are already in place    
        for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)  // **Added n - i - 1**
            if (arr[j] > arr[j+1]) 
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]); 
}
```

more on bubble sort here: [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/)